# Looking up a Name and Value Against a Upper and Lower Bound List

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to perform a Lookup of a Name and Value against a Lookup List which contains the Name, UpperBound, LowerBound and Price. I want to return the price if it falls under the range, for example:

**Sheet1:**

| Name | Quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 5 | ?? |
| Apple | 11 | ?? |
| Apple | 23 | ?? |
| Grape | 9 | ?? |
| Grape | 27 | ?? |
| Grape | 40 | ?? |

I want to get the price above from the following list.

**Sheet 2:**

| Name | Lower Bound | Upper Bound | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 0 | 10 | $10.00 |
| Apple | 11 | 20 | $29.50 |
| Apple | 21 | 30 | $28.20 |
| Grape | 0 | 15 | $22.10 |
| Grape | 16 | 24 | $31.20 |
| Grape | 25 | 50 | $35.20 |

Please note that the above is an example and in the actual sheets I have 1000s of Products and attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet another way:

```
=FILTER($D$2:$D$7,($A$2:$A$7=G2)*($C$2:$C$7>=H2)*($B$2:$B$7<=H2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) with last parameter omitted

```cpp
=MAP(A2:A7,B2:B7,LAMBDA(name,qty,VLOOKUP(qty,FILTER(B11:D16,A11:A16=name),3)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following formula :

[image]

---

```
=LET(x, FILTER(G$2:I$4,$A2=$F$2:$F$4), VLOOKUP($B2,x,3,1))
```

---

Comment: I like this, very similar answer, but is there some input data missing here?

Comment: Yes Sir, when I have posted, OP had only those lines of data rest was missing. So I have not updated, but it will work! Also if i remember OP had currency values as pounds. but they changed it to dollars

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(tblConfig[Price]*
      (tblConfig[Name]=[@Name])*
      (tblConfig[Upper Bound]>=[@Quantity])*
      (tblConfig[Lower Bound]<=[@Quantity]))
```

I named the table for the price ranges `tblConfig`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just use SUMIFS with your criteria:

[image]

Formula in cell C2 and drag down:

```
=SUMIFS($J$2:$J$7;$G$2:$G$7;A2;$H$2:$H$7;"<="&B2;$I$2:$I$7;">="&B2)
```

If you need to multiply the quantity based in the price (which is based on the quantity too) just do:

```
=SUMIFS($J$2:$J$7;$G$2:$G$7;A2;$H$2:$H$7;"<="&B2;$I$2:$I$7;">="&B2)*B2
```

So for example, for 5 apples, because of bounds each apple is 10 so final price would be 50.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following is sufficient:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,FILTER(B$10:D$15,A$10:A$15=A2),3)
```